# Using a http service in Angular 17 with standalone components

Tags: angular, angular17

I have a component (see: it is a *standalone* one):

```
@Component({
  standalone: true, // <--- See here 
  selector: "app-login",
  imports: [FormsModule, CommonModule],
  templateUrl: "./login.component.html",
  styleUrl: "./login.component.css"
})
export class LoginComponent {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService) {}
}
```

And the service is (see, it requires HttpClient to be *injected):*

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
export default class AuthService {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {} // <--- See here: if I remove this httpClient, it works.
}
```

It does not works:

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: R3InjectorError(Standalone[e])[e -> e -> e -> e]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for e!
```

If I remove the httpClient from the constructor of the service, it works (but it does nothing). It seem to me that the injection of the HttpClient inside the service is not working.

Any clue?

Version: Angular 17

PS: lot's of details removed :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you provide `HttpClient` in your `app.config.ts` like this :

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideAnimations(), provideHttpClient()]
};
```

Answer (score 1):

in appConfig you need http client provider

```
export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
providers: [provideRouter(routes), provideHttpClient()]
};
```