Angular v18 Standalone No provider for _HttpClient
I am trying to get data via a Service from a local Express Server
Service
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Artikel } from './artikelInterface';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ArtikelService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) 
  { }

    getAlleArtikel(): Observable<Artikel[]>
    {
    return this.http.get<Artikel[]>('http://localhost:3000/article');
   }
  
}


Receiving Component
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { ArtikelService } from '../artikel.service';
import { Artikel } from '../artikelInterface';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-output',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, HttpClientModule],
  templateUrl: './output.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./output.component.css']
})
export class OutputComponent implements OnInit {
  

  constructor(private artikelService: ArtikelService) {}
  Artikel: Artikel[] = [];

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.artikelService.getAlleArtikel()
      .subscribe(data => this.Artikel = data);
  }
}

Interface
export interface Artikel{
    id: number,
    ueberschrift: string,
    datum: string,
    autor: string,
    tesaer:string,
    text: string,
    tags: string[],
}

I also made shure to test the Server with Postman but it works fine so the issue is somewhere in my Angular code but the only error I get is when I use "ng serve". This issue seems to be quite common and I also tried a couple of the standart solutions but none of them worked for me
Error
R3InjectorError(Standalone[_AppComponent])[_ArtikelService -> _ArtikelService -> _HttpClient -> _HttpClient]: 
  NullInjectorError: No provider for _HttpClient!

at NullInjector.get (/Users/jan/Desktop/BackTest/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:1654:27)
    at R3Injector.get (/Users/jan/Desktop/BackTest/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3093:33)
    at R3Injector.get (/Users/jan/Desktop/BackTest/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3093:33)
    at injectInjectorOnly (/Users/jan/Desktop/BackTest/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:1100:40)
    at Module.ɵɵinject (/Users/jan/Desktop/BackTest/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:1106:42)
    at Object.ArtikelService_Factory (/Users/jan/Desktop/BackTest/src/app/artikel.service.ts:11:28)
    at eval (/Users/jan/Desktop/BackTest/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3219:47)
    at runInInjectorProfilerContext (/Users/jan/Desktop/BackTest/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:866:9)
    at R3Injector.hydrate (/Users/jan/Desktop/BackTest/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3218:21)
    at R3Injector.get (/Users/jan/Desktop/BackTest/node_modules/@angular/core/fesm2022/core.mjs:3082:33



Please see this related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78147611/using-a-http-service-in-angular-17-with-standalone-components/78147657#78147657

@jamakr4 please share the code in main.ts, if you are using app.module.ts please share that also

Since you are using standalone components, you need to add provideHttpClient() in the providers array for bootstrapApplication caller.

seems like you need this in your code:
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [provideHttpClient(withInterceptorsFromDi())],
}).catch(err => console.error(err));

withInterceptorsFromDi() if you wanna you interceptors too, if not:
bootstrapApplication(AppComponent, {
  providers: [provideHttpClient()],
}).catch(err => console.error(err));

